# Parity of $\operatorname{ord}(G) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $ \left ( G,\cdot  \right ) $ be a finite group and $ f:G\rightarrow G,f(x)=x^{2} $, an automorphism.
Prove that $ |G| $ is an odd number.

Comment: What happens if $\vert G \vert$ is even?

Comment: Unrelated observation: $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: In particular, $f$ must be a bijection, and you know that $f(1_G)=1_G$. But if $|G|$ is even, ... ?

Comment: Well, if  $ |G| $ is even, there exists an $ x \in G $ with $ ord(x)=2 $., so f is not injective, which means f is not an automorphism, contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: @ztefelina: That’s exactly right.

Comment: @ztefelina: You’re welcome!